# tooltip displaying at random position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where i have multiple tables in a page and when i mouse over on one column it has to show tooltip at the top position with some data in it. Issue is tooltip is showing randomly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first off, make sure you're correctly terminating your spans (you're missing the ending bracket).

change this:

```
a.tooltip:hover span {
    position: fixed;
```

to this

```
a.tooltip:hover span {
    position: absolute;
```